# Tool for network/infrastructure graph

Tags: linux, networking, infrastructure

I search for Linux a graphic tool to document our network/server infrastructure. A script that converts maybe some textual representation into dot (i.e. graphviz) would be enough.

Nodes should be devices, there should be the possibility that there are multiple connections between nodes (we have multiple machines that have more than one connection (I guess the most is 8 connections we have direct between two machines)), and the endpoints need to contain some attributes, like the name of the endpoint device (e.g. usb0, eth0) as well as e.g. the fqdn in case it has different names for different devices (e.g. we have different names for each computer and its remote managment interface). Also each node should have the possiblitiy to have attributes (e.g. which services are running on the machine). **EDIT**: I also need the ability to make loops (i.e. from one node to itself (but to a different port)).

For sure I could draw it was every vector graphic program (xfig, inkscape,...) but it should be maintainable, i.e. small changes should not require 5 hours  of work and an artist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used xfig and dia for this, and it certainly doesn't take "5 hours of work and an artist" to do small changes.  If you want to describe things textually, writing dot files and running them through graphviz yourself should work fine.